# Bootstrap Typehead not accepting "&" on Google Chrome

Tags: bootstrap-typeahead

I am facing strange issue on Google Chrome, Firefox does not seems to be affected by this problem.

**Reproduce problem**

Go to http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead

type any thing, such as A, once auto suggest appear, try, typing "**&**", it won't accept till auto suggest is displayed.

I tried Google-ing for it, but did not find any thing. also, it's not a reported problem : https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues?labels=js&state=open

can someone confirm if they are also facing this issue? Or if it is already reported with Bootstrap.

Thanks in Advance

Ravish

Comment: Just a note, this is a problem on IE as well, re-produced on IE8/9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution:

I've reported this issue on Bootstrap's Github page: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/8190

They have informed that Bootstrap Typeahead has been deprecated, and they plan to use Twiter Typehead going forward : http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/

Twiter typehead does not contains above reported problem. Will be using Twitter Typehead instead Bootstrap Typehead.

Thanks.